# Replacing Alphabets with numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was doing an exercise on converting a string's alphabets to its numbers.
My program is returning a blank string.
Can anyone help.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
def alphabet_position(text):
    numText = []
    LETTERS = {}
    for letter, index in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, start=1):
        letters = {letter : str(index)}
        LETTERS.update(letters)
    newText = text.lower()
    for i in newText:
        if i in LETTERS:
            numText.append(LETTERS[i])
    return " ".join(numText)

a = alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
print(a)
```

Comment: Instead of over-engineering `LETTERS.update(letters)` why not just do `LETTERS[letter] = str(index)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `enumerate(data)` built-in function generates a tuple containing a pair of index-value for every value in `data`.

Hence, in your first loop, `letter` actually refers to an index, and `index` refers to a letter. It turns out that the keys in your dictionary `LETTERS` are numbers, not characters (letters).

On the other hand, the `in` membership test in dictionaries looks for **keys**, not values. You are, then, testing letters within the keys of your dictionary; however, in your dict, keys are the indices! The test in the `if` statement never returns `True`.

In order for your code to work, simply change the tuple assignment `letter, index` in your first `for` loop to `index, letter`, and it should work.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
def alphabet_position(text):
numText = []
LETTERS = {}
for index, letter in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, start=1):
    letters = {letter : str(index)}
    LETTERS.update(letters)
newText = text.lower()
for i in newText:
    if i in LETTERS:
        numText.append(LETTERS[i])
return " ".join(numText)


a = alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
print(a)
```

Sometimes it helps to take a look at the Python Standard Manual/Documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/).
For beginners, using `print()` to dump your variables are very useful in checking what is happening inside your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you Print the LETTERS Map generated it has integer as keys and corresponding character as value. Like:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z'}
```

Resulting in if loop to be always false causing the empty string.

```
for i in newText:
    if i in LETTERS:
        numText.append(LETTERS[i])
```

you can swap the key value pair of LETTERS while generating it, it should work fine.